How to have a good alveolation when baking at a low temperature?
I wonder if it is possible to have a good alveolation when baking at a low temperature.
I would like to have big alveoli, a large cornice, and an irregular alveolation.
About the temperature, i usually bake at 250°C or 300°C, 482°F or 572°F, in a wood stove oven, or in an electric domestic oven.
My pizza stone is only 1 cm (0.4 inch) thick, and I wonder if a 4 cm (1.6 inches) thick pizza stone would give a better alveolation ?
I thought to increase hydration to 70% or more, but maybe the dough will be more difficult to knead and longer to bake in the oven.
